# Find $\int e^{x^4}(x+x^3+2x^5)e^{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Find $\int e^{x^4}(x+x^3+2x^5)e^{x^2}dx$

---

$$I=\int e^{x^4}(x+x^3+2x^5)e^{x^2}dx$$
$$I=\int e^{x^4}(1+x^2+2x^4)e^{x^2}xdx$$
Let $x^2=t$
$I=\int e^{t^2}(1+t+2t^2)e^t\frac{dt}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{t^2+t}(1+t+2t^2)dt$
I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As $\dfrac{d(x^4+x^2)}{dx}=4x^3+2x$

$$\int e^{x^4+x^2}(2x+2x^3+4x^5)dx=\int[e^{x^4+x^2}x^2(2x+4x^3)+e^{x^4+x^2}(2x)dx$$

which is clearly of the from  $$\int e^{f(x)}[g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)]dx=e^{f(x)}g(x)+K$$

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the answer is given by an elementary function, it has to be a function of the form $p(x) e^{x^2+x^4}$ with $p(x)$ being a quadratic polynomial. We have

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^2 e^{x^2+x^4} = 2(x+x^3+2x^5)e^{x^2+x^4} $$
hence such inspired guess immediately leads to
$$ \int (x+x^3+2x^5) e^{x^2+x^4}\,dx = C+\frac{x^2}{2}e^{x^2+x^4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(t)=\frac{1}{2t+1}e^{t^2+t}$ and $v(t)=1+t+2t^2.$

By integration by parts you have
$$u(t)v(t)=\int u'(t)v(t)dt+\int u(t)v'(t)dt$$
that is
$$ \frac{1}{2t+1}e^{t^2+t}(1+t+2t^2)=\int e^{t^2+t}(1+t+2t^2)dt+\int \frac{1}{2t+1}e^{t^2+t}(2t+1)dt$$$$=2I+\int e^{t^2+t}dt=2I+\frac{e^{t^2+t}}{2t+1}$$
Now simply solve for $I$:
$$I=\frac{(t+2t^2)e^{t^2+t}}{2(2t+1)}=\frac{te^{t^2+t}}{2}+C$$